# change background color based on another cell color google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to change the background color of a cell based on another cell color in google sheets.

I will give an example:
А1: оrder date - 11.12.22
B1: order processing - 14 days
C1: send the order =A1+B1

C1: If date is today - yellow, if date is before today red.

I want if A1 color changed to green (meaning the order is sent), C1 to change automatically back to transparent. Is that possible?

Comment: thank you for the kind respond, have a great week!

Answer (score 0):

custom formula for yellow:

```
=A1=TODAY()
```

and red:

```
=A1=TODAY()-1
```